# An unexpected error occurred when uploading your package

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli

I am facing an unexpected error occurrance while uploading the Managed package of an CPQ Instance, mentioning like "An unexpected error occurred when uploading your package. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following error code: 86255252-530166 (-1825867773)".

I am not understanding what this error regards. And even I checked code coverage , it is 84%.

Comment: Ultimately, you'll have to contact support. Most of us here are not salesforce.com employees and therefore don't have access to the log files that the error number indicates.